# App Approved but IAP's Waiting for review, not getting reviewed

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

We have had an App go through the approval cycle several times and while the status went into "Pending Developer Release", our IAP's never changed out of the "Waiting for Review" status.  We have tried resubmitting and also creating new product ID's and then resubmitting.

Both times yielded the same result.  Are we missing something or is there something we are missing?

Comment: Have you contacted the support already?

Comment: Close voters: iTunes Connect is specifically on-topic here. This question is not off-topic.

Comment: iTunes Connect is on-topic as such, but this seems to be question which should be addressed to the support team first.

Comment: Thanks Patrix, I've gone through all my options for the iTunes Connect Support.  I saw a similar question here so thought this would be acceptable.

Comment: I've reopen d this and put the answer. Dig into the guide and open a case with as specific a question about the process as you can.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed from experience, that even when your app is approved, the IAP can take quite a while to get approved, especially when you have translated the IAP in (many) other languages, it seems that those needs to go to different teams that can understand the translation, to see if you deliver on your promise.

So in that mean time users get "Product not available" in the App. In my latest app I have 2 IAPs, the 2st one is approved 2 days after the App approval, the second which has more languages, is not yet approved (3rd day now).

Answer (score 0):

Apple has support for developers as part of your service. Have you opened a Dev support ticket asking where the review process is documented?

- https://developer.apple.com/support/

Also, if the app is pending developer release, you can ask support how to push it to released if you follow the steps in the guide.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html